# how to add a hyperlink to a cell using openxml c#?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, export-to-excel

I have this method, that creates an excel file, is working just fine, but the hyperlinks are not attached to the cells, so even though the style is fine, you can't click on the cell. I debug the method and is in fact adding the correct url, and then i explored the xml file and the relashionship is present. this is my method

```
public byte[] GenerateExcel(DataTable data, DataTable columns)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();

            // Add default workbook view
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
            workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>().Stylesheet = CreateStylesheetExport();

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

            // Add sheet view
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetViews(new SheetView() { WorkbookViewId = 0, ShowGridLines = new BooleanValue(false) }), new SheetData());

            List<Hyperlink> hyperlinkList = new List<Hyperlink>();

            Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
            string relationshipId = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
            uint sheetId = 1;
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Sheet 1" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            Row headerRow = new Row();

            // Set header row height
            double headerRowHeightInInches = 2.5;
            headerRow.Height = new DoubleValue(headerRowHeightInInches * 20);
            headerRow.CustomHeight = true;

            foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
            {
                DataRow colInfo = columns.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["FieldName"].ToString() == column.ColumnName);

                string headerText = column.ColumnName;  // default to the original value
                if (colInfo != null && colInfo["FieldDisplay"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    headerText = colInfo["FieldDisplay"].ToString();
                }

                Cell headerCell = new Cell()
                {
                    DataType = CellValues.String,
                    CellValue = new CellValue(headerText),
                    StyleIndex = 9 // Bold header style index
                };
                headerRow.AppendChild(headerCell);
            }
            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            Columns columnSettings = new Columns();
            uint columnIndex = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
            {
                DataRow colInfo = columns.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["FieldName"].ToString() == column.ColumnName);
                double columnWidth = 20;  // default width
                if (colInfo != null && colInfo["FieldWidth"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    double columnWidthUn = Convert.ToDouble(colInfo["FieldWidth"]);
                    columnWidth = (columnWidthUn / 10) + 8;
                    if (columnWidth < 20)
                        columnWidth = 20;
                }
                columnSettings.Append(new Column() { Min = columnIndex, Max = columnIndex, Width = columnWidth, CustomWidth = true });
                columnIndex++;
            }
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(columnSettings, sheetData);

            foreach (DataRow dr in data.Rows)
            {
                Row row = new Row();
                foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                {
                    DataRow colInfo = columns.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r["FieldName"].ToString() == column.ColumnName);

                    if (colInfo != null)
                    {
                        string dataType = colInfo["FieldDataType"].ToString();
                        string justification = colInfo["FieldJustification"].ToString();

                        uint styleIndex = GetStyleIndexByDataTypeAndJustification(dataType, justification);

                        Cell cell = new Cell();
                        cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;

                        switch (dataType)
                        {
                            case "M": // Monetary
                            case "I": // Integer
                                cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                                break;
                            case "D": // Date
                                cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
                                break;
                            default: // Text
                                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                                break;
                        }

                        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dr[column].ToString());

                        if (colInfo.Table.Columns.Contains("FieldLink") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(colInfo["FieldLink"].ToString()))
                        {
                            string baseFieldLink = colInfo["FieldLink"].ToString();

                            baseFieldLink = baseFieldLink.Replace("\"", "");
                            baseFieldLink = baseFieldLink.Replace(" & ", "").Replace(" &", "").Replace("& ", "");
                            baseFieldLink = Regex.Replace(baseFieldLink, "&+", "&");
                            baseFieldLink = baseFieldLink.Replace(":49567&", ":49567");

                            string partsInventoryId = dr["partsInventoryId"].ToString();
                            string companyId = dr["companyId"].ToString();

                            baseFieldLink = baseFieldLink.Replace("Fields!partsInventoryId.Value", partsInventoryId)
                                                         .Replace("Fields!companyId.Value", companyId);

                            Uri hyperlinkUri;
                            try
                            {
                                hyperlinkUri = new Uri(baseFieldLink, UriKind.Absolute);
                            }
                            catch (UriFormatException)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            string hyperlinkId = "rId" + (worksheetPart.HyperlinkRelationships.Count() + 1).ToString();
                            Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink { Reference = cell.CellReference, Id = hyperlinkId };
                            hyperlinkList.Add(hyperlink);
                            worksheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(hyperlinkUri, true, hyperlinkId);
                            cell.StyleIndex = 10;
                        }
                        row.AppendChild(cell);
                    }
                }
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
            }

            if (hyperlinkList.Count > 0)
            {
                Hyperlinks hyperlinks = new Hyperlinks();
                foreach (var link in hyperlinkList)
                {
                    hyperlinks.Append(link);
                }
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(hyperlinks, worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>());
            }

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            document.Close();

            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug it but everything seems fine